# How to get the Focus on one of Buttons of JQuery Dialog on ASP.NET MVC page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-dialog

I have an ASP.NET MVC page(Registration). On loading the page, i am calling Jquery Dialog with **Agree** and **Disagree** buttons on that Dialog.

1). How to set the **focus to Agree button** by default?

2). How to disable the **X (Close) Mark** that is on Top right corner? (So that i don't want the user to close that dialog simply).

Code:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false,
        autoOpen: <%= ViewData["autoOpen"] %>,
        height: 400,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Disagree': function() {
                location.href = "/";
            },
            'Agree': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $(this).focus();
            }
        },
        beforeclose: function(event, ui) {
            var i = event.target.id;
            var j = 0;
        }
    });
```

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use this:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({

     open: function(event, ui) {

          $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); // Hide the [x] button

          $(":button:contains('Ok')").focus(); // Set focus to the [Ok] button
     }

});
```